# Does React Semantic UI Search Support Multiselection?

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I notice that for dropdown it allows for multiple selection:

https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown
[image]

However, I notice that this isn't the same with search.
https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/search

[image]

Is it possible to get the same functionality where every time you press enter or select an item in the search drop down that it appears as a object within the search bar. This would make the usage of the drop down and the search bar consistent?

Or is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 0):

The Semantic-ui-react Dropdown component supports a search property.  My suggestion would be to use the Dropdown component instead of the search component if you would like to allow for multiple selections.
[Dropdown Component](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown)

```
<Dropdown selection multiple search { ...otherProps } />
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to 'add' any options? If I add an item it returns to the blank state, is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: What do you mean add options?  I would check your `onChange` event handler if you're selecting a result and it's not being added to your value array.

Comment: My bad! I found out how to do it using state, all good! thanks